# SecKeychainFindGenericPassword not working for osx

Tags: macos, passwords, keychain

Following a piece of code I am using to get the password stored in my custom Keychain

```
-(OSStatus *)getPasswordFromKeyChain:(NSString *)username{
OSStatus status;

[self createKeyChainIfNotExists];

const char *cService_name = "Mac Google Analytics App";
UInt32 service_length = strlen(cService_name);

const char *cUser_name = [username cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UInt32 username_length = strlen(cUser_name);

void *passwordData = nil; 
SecKeychainItemRef itemRef = nil;
UInt32 passwordLength = nil;

status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
                                        mSecKeychainRef,            // default keychain
                                        service_length,  // length of service name
                                        cService_name,    // service name
                                        username_length,// length of account name
                                        cUser_name,    // account name
                                        &passwordLength,  // length of password
                                        passwordData,        // pointer to password data
                                        NULL             // the item reference
                                        );

return status;
}
```

I wonder what is wrong in this code, as the it never comes out of this call:

```
SecKeychainFindGenericPassword
```

It's pointed to the error [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9q2o.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass null for the default keychain, and you need a pointer to the passwordData. That should at least get you a return status to tell if the strings are correct for your service & account.

```
    status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(NULL,            // default keychain
                                            service_length,  // length of service name
                                            cService_name,    // service name
                                            username_length,// length of account name
                                            cUser_name,    // account name
                                            &passwordLength,  // length of password
                                            &passwordData,        // pointer to password data
                                            NULL             // the item reference
                                            );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Now I have the password in passwordData... how do I convert that into NSString as I want to use it further in my application

Comment: [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:passwordData length:passwordLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];